# How to get the average (or sum, count, etc.) of variables for each group ID?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with a list of IDs and other variables like so:

```
Student_ID       Score
6                94
2                63
6                100
7                44
6                97
2                67
```

I would like to create another data frame that consists of just the Student_ID and average score like this:

```
Student_ID       Avg_Score
2                65
6                97
7                44
```

The actual data set is much larger, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` package:

```
df %>% group_by(Student_ID) %>% summarise(Avg_Score = mean(Score))


# # A tibble: 3 x 2 
#   Student_ID Avg_Score 
#        <int>     <dbl> 
# 1          2        65 
# 2          6        97 
# 3          7        44
```

You can also use `aggregate` in base R:

```
aggregate( Score ~ Student_ID, df, mean) #column name will remain as "Score"

#   Student_ID Score 
# 1          2    65 
# 2          6    97 
# 3          7    44
```

Comment: You can replace `mean` with `sum` or `count` or other functions.